Debian/Gnome in xdmcp - Hot Corner does not work

X Server:   Cygwin/X fullscreen on Windows 11
X Client:   Gnome desktop on Debian 12.5

I realize this could be an issue with Cygwin/X, but I'd like to confirm that this is not a problem with xdmcp before I post on the Cygwin support list.
Gnome's hot-corner functionality (or the hot-bottom-edge plugin) does not work in an xdmcp session.  On the HDMI console connected to the Debian system hot-corner works just fine, and I don't have a second Linux system to use as a test XServer.
Is this a known limitation?
